# Community wiki after reformat clash

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

This question went to community wiki mode after 3 or 4 people clashed trying to reformat it:

[How can I select none duplicate rows with inner join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822174/how-can-i-select-none-duplicate-rows-with-inner-join)

Is there a way to return it to a normal question?

Comment: Yes, but it will require a virgin sacrifice.

Comment: Those shouldn't be too hard to find on SO. ;)

Comment: Thank you gnostradamus for volunteering.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fit the criteria... and I'll be able to prove that come February when `gnovice 2.0` is released and the programming world gets another much-needed female (if I have anything to say about it, that is).

Comment: What kind of edit war was **THAT?**

Comment: @Smurfsnorting Farfulburger: Don't thinking it was an edit war, just various people reformatting it, then finding that ** does not mean bold in code blocks, then finding out <BR> is not a line break in a code block

Comment: @Andomar: Yep, trying to get rid of the <BR> here, along with the sql-server tag that went AWOL.

Comment: Whatever the cause, that edit history looked really bizarre. :) Glad to know it wasn't an intentional war, though!

Comment: Looking at the timestamps. W O W. Lots of near-simultaneous activity there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741).

Answer (score 1):

Good lord, 13 revisions by 6 users?

We do offer real-time (well, 40 seconds) edit notifications, by the way. So you should know when this happens, unless you're lightning quick with your edit.

Comment: Improper markdown offends my OCD

Comment: New users don't format their SQL, that's something many people edit without thinking, definitely less than 40 seconds